# Call method in user control from one of it's modules

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have created a custom usercontrol which raises events within itself during errors to be passed to whatever application is utilizing the usercontrol. I would like to raise these same events from modules within the user control's code by calling a method within the user control itself. An example for what I am trying to do would be:

```
Public Class MyUserControl
    Public Event MyErrorEvent(Ex as Exception)

    Public Sub RaiseAnErrorSub(Ex as Exception)
        RaiseEvent MyErrorEvent(Ex)
    End Sub
End Class 


Public Module
    Public Sub DoSomething()
        'Performs an operation
         'An Error could happen here
         'Need to raise the usercontrol's event at this point....
         RaiseAnErrorSub(Ex) 'How can this call the usercontrol of this module?
    End Sub     
End Module
```

Is there a way to call the existing instance of the usercontrol and thereby, it's contained methods?

Comment: Where exactly is this module located? In the `UserControl.vb` file? If so, there is no relationship between the module and the class. To be able to call the method that raises an exception elswwhere, you can simply call `usercontrol1.RaiseAnErrorSub(Ex)`.

Comment: preciousbetine: The module is a separate file, withing the same project as the file MyUserControl Class. From within a method in the Module, trying MyUserControl.RaiseAnErrorSub(Ex) results in "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". How can the module method call a method in the MyUserControl instance that isn't created until the usercontrol is utilized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question might be easier to answer if we knew exactly what the usercontrol was for and why it needs to handle exceptions. But even without that information there are only so many potential solutions to this type of problem, depending on how you want it to work.

---

If you have **one** particular instance of your usercontrol in your project that you want to raise the event, you need to have a reference to that instance. Since you want to access this instance from a `Module` I would suggest creating a field in the `Module` to hold that reference. You could add the following:

```
Public UserControlInstance As [YourUserControlTypeHere]
```

Since this would be in a `Module` it is automatically [`Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) (which judging by your question is a programming concept you might want to read up on). This allows it to be referenced from anywhere in the project without using an instance.

You would want to set `UserControlInstance` to the instance of your usercontrol when that usercontrol is created. For example, if your usercontrol is part of a `Window` or `Form` you could set `UserControlInstance` from the constructor (`Public Sub New`) of that `Window` or `Form`.

---

On the other hand, if you want **any and all** instances of your usercontrol to raise the event whenever `RaiseAnErrorSub` is called, you can make both `RaiseAnErrorSub` and `MyErrorEvent` `Shared`, like so:

```
Public Shared Event MyErrorEvent(Ex as Exception)

Public Shared Sub RaiseAnErrorSub(Ex as Exception)
    RaiseEvent MyErrorEvent(Ex)
End Sub
```

This way, you could call `RaiseAnErrorSub` from anywhere in the project and all instances of your usercontrol would raise the event (effectively, anyway).

Comment: Thanks, Keith. I have done as you suggested (making a more public reference to the user control instance available). Using a sub to call the raise event makes it "raisable" by other modules and gets around the inability of RaiseEvent to be more public itself. Thank you.